# Android setText in ListView causes null pointer

Tags: android, settext

Here is my problem, I am trying to setText from a ListView. The problem is, I will get an error because (according to my logs) the setContentView of my main activity does not match up with the TextView i want to setText from another .xml (contactList.xml)

Jobs Activity (Main)

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.jobs);
    vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    TextView assigned = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.assigned);



    new ParseJobs().execute();
```

ParseJobs() Method

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);



        if (ACKNOWLEDGED.contains("False")) {


            /** Updating parsed JSON data into ListView */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Jobs.this, contactList, R.layout.list_item, new String[] { job, pays, ready_at }, new int[] { R.id.job1, R.id.pays1, R.id.ready_at1 });
            setListAdapter(adapter);        

            //TextView readyORdue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.readyORdue);
            //readyORdue.setText("Ready At:");
        }

        if (ACKNOWLEDGED.contains("True")) {

            /** Updating parsed JSON data into ListView */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Jobs.this, contactList, R.layout.list_item, new String[] { job, pays, due_by }, new int[] { R.id.job1, R.id.pays1, R.id.due_by1 });
            setListAdapter(adapter);    

            //TextView readyORdue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.readyORdue);
            //readyORdue.setText("Due By:");
        }


        VerifyDriver.dismiss();

    }
}
```

Notice in my ParseJobs Method, I am trying to to update the TextView "readyORdue" but I will get an error because, that TextView belongs to SimpleAdapter contactList.xml

So my question is, how would i setText a textview from my contactList XML layout?

Heres My Logs:

```
 07-17 15:55:16.703: W/dalvikvm(4387): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015578)
 07-17 15:55:16.703: E/AndroidRuntime(4387): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 07-17 15:55:16.703: E/AndroidRuntime(4387): java.lang.NullPointerException
 07-17 15:55:16.703: E/AndroidRuntime(4387):    at com.jetdelivery.mobile.Jobs$ParseJobs.onPostExecute(Jobs.java:287)
 07-17 15:55:16.703: E/AndroidRuntime(4387):    at com.jetdelivery.mobile.Jobs$ParseJobs.onPostExecute(Jobs.java:1)
 07-17 15:55:16.703: E/AndroidRuntime(4387):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
 07-17 15:55:16.703: E/AndroidRuntime(4387):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
 07-17 15:55:16.703: E/AndroidRuntime(4387):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
 07-17 15:55:16.703: E/AndroidRuntime(4387):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 07-17 15:55:16.703: E/AndroidRuntime(4387):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
 07-17 15:55:16.703: E/AndroidRuntime(4387):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
 07-17 15:55:16.703: E/AndroidRuntime(4387):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 07-17 15:55:16.703: E/AndroidRuntime(4387):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-17 15:55:16.703: E/AndroidRuntime(4387):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
07-17 15:55:16.703: E/AndroidRuntime(4387):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
07-17 15:55:16.703: E/AndroidRuntime(4387):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Line 287 is "readyORdue.setText("Ready At:");"

Comment: Can you post LogCat with exact error? R.id.readyORdue - layout xml will also help

Comment: May I ask just one question? Why are you trying to set an adapter in under onPostExecute also creating one in a different thread than your UI thread. Thinking that it might actually work out!

Comment: Just updated my post with logs

Comment: my adapter is actually working, they are both actually working, the view just depends on whether the string "ACKNOWLEDGED" is true or false.

Comment: @JohnNguyen : Your question isn't clear. What does `contactList.xml` actually do? You say that `readyORdue` is part of it but how is it displayed and where?

Comment: If I got you correct, If you are trying to use another layout file (contactList XML) as you described, first you need to inflate it. LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService      (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View contactList= inflater.inflate(R.layout.some_layout, parent, false);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use another layout file "contactList.xml" as you described, first you need to inflate it.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
View contactList= inflater.inflate(R.layout.contactList, false);
```

Now

```
TextView readyORdue = (TextView)contactList.findViewById(R.id.readyORdue);
```

will give you needed TextView, add this view to some container in your R.layout.jobs to make it visible.

Answer (score 0):

setListAdapter is something related to ListActivity and ListActivity has her own layout content so ...you can't setContentView in a ListActivity
What you could do is to create your own layout that contain the list and  the TextView readyORdue & TextView assigned
and just one thing why you are using two if ? you can just set 
        if(firstCondition) {
        ..
       }else 
             ...

Answer (score 0):

Are these in the same class? If so, I would define the `readyORdue` in your `MainActivity`. Your threads should not be defining user interface objects if you can avoid it; that is why you have `onCreate()`.

```
public class MainActivity {
    private TextView readyORDue;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.jobs);
        vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        TextView assigned = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.assigned);

        readyORDue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.readyORdue);

        new ParseJobs().execute();
    }
}
```

Then in your Parser

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if (ACKNOWLEDGED.contains("False")) {


        /** Updating parsed JSON data into ListView */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Jobs.this, contactList, R.layout.list_item, new String[] { job, pays, ready_at }, new int[] { R.id.job1, R.id.pays1, R.id.ready_at1 });
        setListAdapter(adapter);        

        readyORdue.setText("Ready At:");
    }

    if (ACKNOWLEDGED.contains("True")) {

        /** Updating parsed JSON data into ListView */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Jobs.this, contactList, R.layout.list_item, new String[] { job, pays, due_by }, new int[] { R.id.job1, R.id.pays1, R.id.due_by1 });
        setListAdapter(adapter);    

        readyORdue.setText("Due By:");
    }


    VerifyDriver.dismiss();

}
```

Note: you will probably have to use [`runOnUiThread`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) for your setText() calls.